# Prove the following

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, induction

Given a positive integer $n$ show that there exists an even integer $k$ so that $3n-1 < k + 1 < 3n+2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I believe you mean "Prove the following".

Comment: @RobertIsrael don't know how to start. My thought is that 3n and 3n+3 are consecutive multiples of 3. So there must lie an even integer k in between them. So we get 3n < k < 3n+3. Stuck after that.

Comment: @JohnDouma believe this is a Math forum and not and English one! Have changed it anyways..

Comment: You're close. What you want is an even integer between $3n-2$ and $3n+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want $k$ to be even and such that $3n-2 < k < 3n+1$ now if $n$ is even, then we have that $n=2m$ for some positive integer $m$ and so $3n-2=6m-2$ is even and $3n+1=6m+1$ is odd. Let $k=6m$ and you are done. If $n$ is odd, we have $n=2m+1$ and we have that $3n-2=6m+3-2=6m+1$ and $6m+3+1 = 6m+4$ let $k=6m+2$.

Generally, it helps to split such $n'$s up into odd and even cases.

Edit: As was mentioned by John Douma in the comments, this is overkill on calculation. As they said, just need to see that between $3n-1$ and $3n+2$ there are two numbers, $3n$ or $3n+1$ depending on $n$ being odd or even you chose $k$ to be the one of these two that are even.

Comment: You don't need so much calculation. The only numbers between $3n-1$ and $3n+2$ are $3n$ and $3n+1$. If $3n$ is odd then $k=3n-1$, otherwise $k=3n$.